# Uncaught ReferenceError: _classCallCheck is not defined

Tags: html5, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babel

Estoy obteniendo este error en la consola de mi navegador, que no deja cargar mi juego en HTML5:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _classCallCheck is not defined
at new WebSocketClient (WebSocketClient.js:17:5)
at initSocket (socket.js:35:12)
at eval (index.js:332:55)
at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=148.113.182.240&port=8080&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&overlay=true&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true (yukon.js:2526:1)
at __webpack_require__ (yukon.js:11907:42)
at yukon.js:11976:11
at yukon.js:11979:12
```

He intentado con ChatGTP, que me indica instalar nuevamente Babel, pero no funciona, no encuentro nada en Google entonces quiero saber si alguien puede ser tan amable de ayudarme.